# Restricting user input to 64 bits?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, string-length

new to Python and i'm just wondering how to restrict the user input to make sure that they enter 64 bits

at the moment i've got this code

```
while True:
num = input('Please enter 64-bits')
if len(num=4)
    print ('Accepted')
    break
else:
    print ('Not Accepted, try again')
```

i know that line 3 is wrong but I'm pretty sure I have to use len in some way, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by entering 64-bits? You mean a integer number that can be represented in binary using at most 64 bits? Or a binary string of 1s and 0s of length 64? Or a number that requires *exactly* 64 bits to represent (so between 9223372036854775808 and 18446744073709551615)?

Comment: a binary string of 1s and 0s of length 64 :)

Comment: You already know about `len`, what's the problem?

Comment: @thg435 just figuring out how to set the length to equal 64

Comment: @user2058186: you don't need to _set_ it, just check if it equals 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520969/3061818) from falsetru won't work if the number starts with leading zeroes and you want to accept this as valid input.

You may want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` -- this way you'll get the raw string that the user enters.  Then you can easily test the length of that string, in addition to converting the number with `int(<x>, 2)`.  Something like this, for instance:

```
while True:
    raw = raw_input('Please enter 64 bits: ')
    try:
        num = int(raw,2)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid binary number")
        continue
    if len(raw)==64:
        print ('Accepted')
        break
    else:
        print ('Not Accepted, need exactly 64 bits.  Try again')
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using [`int.bit_length`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#int.bit_length) method? (if you mean `num` is integer number)

```
>>> (1).bit_length()
1
>>> (2 ** 10).bit_length()
11
>>> (1 << 63).bit_length()
64
```

---

**UPDATE**

First convert the input string into number using `int` (with 2 as base).

```
>>> int('000001', 2)
1
>>> int('000001', 2).bit_length()
1
>>> int('00101', 2)
5
>>> int('00101', 2).bit_length()
3
```